# POST request works in postman but not with react axios using spring boot backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, postman

From the react console I get the error message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()" pointing to url ":8080/api/review-add"

From spring boot backend I get the error message "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.reactspringboot.bookclubbackend.entity.Review.account"

Problem is when perform a POST Request in postman I don't get an error and the object is posted into the database.

Here is the files from spring boot backend:

Forum.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Forum")
public class Forum {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="book_name")
    private String bookName;

    @Column(name="book_image")
    private String bookImage;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "forum", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    public Forum() {
    }

    public Forum(String bookName, String bookImage, String description, List<Review> reviews) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.bookImage = bookImage;
        this.description = description;
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getBookImage() {
        return bookImage;
    }

    public void setBookImage(String bookImage) {
        this.bookImage = bookImage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    // using 'JsonProperty' to prevent infinite recursion
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public List<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }
}
```

Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="account_name")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="profile_image")
    private String profileImage;

    @Column(name="role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name="date_joined")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date dateJoined;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(String accountName, String password, String email, String profileImage, String role, Date dateJoined, List<Review> reviews) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.role = role;
        this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Date getDateJoined() {
        return dateJoined;
    }

    public void setDateJoined(Date dateJoined) {
        this.dateJoined = dateJoined;
    }

    // using 'JsonProperty' to prevent infinite recursion
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    public List<Review> getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }
}
```

Review.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="review")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="date_posted")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date datePosted;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="comment")
    private String comment;

    @Column(name="star_rating")
    private double starRating;


    //@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id",nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Account account;


    //@JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "forum_id",nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Forum forum;


    public Review() {
    }

    public Review(Date datePosted, String comment, double starRating, Account account, Forum forum) {
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.starRating = starRating;
        this.account = account;
        this.forum = forum;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getDatePosted() {
        return datePosted;
    }

    public void setDatePosted(Date datePosted) {
        this.datePosted = datePosted;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public double getStarRating() {
        return starRating;
    }

    public void setStarRating(double starRating) {
        this.starRating = starRating;
    }

    public Account getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(Account account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    public Forum getForum() {
        return forum;
    }

    public void setForum(Forum forum) {
        this.forum = forum;
    }
}
```

ReviewRepository.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Review, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Review r where r.forum_id = :forum_id", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Review> getReviewsUsingForumId(@Param("forum_id") Long forum_id);
}
```

ReviewController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class ReviewController {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewRepository reviewRepository;


    // create review rest api
    //@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping("/review-add")
    public Review createReview(@RequestBody Review review) {
        return reviewRepository.save(review);
    }

    @GetMapping("/forum-reviews/{forumId}")
    public List<Review> getReviewsByForumId(@RequestBody @PathVariable Long forumId) {
        return reviewRepository.getReviewsUsingForumId(forumId);
    }
}
```

From React frontend

PostComponent.js

```
function PostComponent() {

    // right now only using static data for testing
    const [review, setReview] = useState({datePosted: "2023-07-26", comment: "", 
                                          starRating: 5.0,
                                          account: {
                                            id: 1
                                          },
                                          forum: {
                                            id: 1
                                          }});
    
    const postURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/review-add";

    function changeHandler (event) {    
        setReview({comment: event.target.value});
    }

    function submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post(postURL, review)
          
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(review.comment)
    }, [review]);

    return ( 
        <div>
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Post Review</h2>
                <form onSubmit={(event) => submit(event)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Comment</label>
                        <input placeholder="Commet here" name="comment" className="form=control"
                            value={review.comment} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                    </div>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) 
}

export default PostComponent;
```

In postman body I choose raw and set to JSON and when I use this POST request for 'Review' entity, it works:

```
{
    "datePosted": "2023-07-26",
    "comment": "From postman.",
    "starRating": 5.0,
    "account": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "forum": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

The forum with id 1 and account with id 1 exist in the database.

If anyone can help me or point me towards solving this issue I would appreciate it. I've been stuck on this problem for days and I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is expecting this entire payload:

```
{
    "datePosted": "2023-07-26",
    "comment": "From postman.",
    "starRating": 5.0,
    "account": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "forum": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

It won't receive that after you've done this:

```
setReview({comment: event.target.value});
```

It would only receive:

```
{
    "comment": "From postman."
}
```

When you only want to update one property in state, the update still needs to include the rest of the object in order to preserve the entire object:

```
setReview({...review, comment: event.target.value});
```

or:

```
setReview(r => ({...r, comment: event.target.value}));
```

---

As an aside... Your browser's debugging tools would help you narrow down this exact problem.  You could observe the payload being sent in the AJAX request, see that it's not what you expect, and immediately rule out **all** server-side code as the culprit and start focusing on client-side debugging.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. I was following a tutorial where their entity/model only had one property aside from id, I guess that is why it worked for them.